# How do I make my working directory update automatically whenever I push to a bare repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a bare repository on my server that I push to in /var/www/repos/my_project . I want to set up my workflow so that when I push to said repository my working directory will automatically update the changes. My working directory would be in something like /var/www/my_live_site . Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I looked around online, but couldn't find any good instructions or resources.

Comment: I would probably recommend **not** putting the bare repository under `/var/www`. Something like `/var/git` or `/var/repos` instead. It is not a web site and the fewer things the web server has access to, the better. Also don't forget to hide `/var/www/my_live_site/.git` from the web server, preferably by making it unreadable to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a `post-update` (or `post-receive`, they are equivalent for this purpose) hook in the bare repository, that will run `git pull` in context of the working directory.

That means put a script to `/var/www/repos/my_project/hooks/post-update` containing

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/my_live_site
git pull
```

and make it executable. You may than want to extend it to only run if the master was pushed (`post-update` hook gets names of all pushed refs as arguments, so check that master is among them), send an email if the pull fails and such, but this should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did this and it doesn't seem to work. When you say make it executable, what do you mean exactly? I added the pull script to post-recieve and it doesn't seem to do anything. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: @SpencerCooley, I mean making it executable. As in, setting the executable permission. `chmod a+x`, probably.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never put WorkingCopy of any VCS under web-root (you show **full history of development** and some more private data in case of DVCS)
2. Use `git archive` in post-* hook for updating site, as Jan already suggested

Comment: If it has the permissions set so the web server can't access the repository data, it's as good as putting it outside of the document root. Of course once you have demilitarized zone, the repository data should never even enter it, so than it would be `git archive` from remote host and using ssh trigger.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about this. Where do you suggest the best place to put repos is?

Comment: @JanHudec - you forgot about **ordinary hack**, where attacker can get **shell**

Comment: @SpencerCooley - outside web-space, maintain site as unversioned files

Comment: @LazyBadger, no, I didn't. If the shell runs with the credentials of the web server, *permissions* (as in `700` and different owner than the web server) still hold. And if it's root, being outside document root won't protect it. For the later, the only safe place is on separate server.